# Definition in some old paper about formal power series (automata theory) Part 2

Tags: automata-theory, definitions

I now know that $K \langle A \rangle$ is the set of all formal power series with finite support for some alphabet $A$ and field $K$. Now I have another question.

Later this expression comes up $\lambda \mu (K\langle A \rangle) = K^{1 \times n}$, where $\lambda \in K^{1 \times n}$ and $\mu$ a function from $A^{*}$ to $K^{n \times n}$. Shouldn‘t it make more sense if $K \langle A \rangle$ is a set of words, because $\mu$ can’t work with a set of polynomials? Or can anyone explain what set $\mu (K\langle A \rangle)$ specifies?

Here the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019097001622

Here another one which uses the same notation page 111 (and if you can’t access the first one): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750000298X

Comment: Isn't a formal power series with finite support the same thing as a polynomial? In the noncommutative case such polynomials would correspond to linear combinations of finite words.

Comment: I don't have time to look into those papers, but could this simply be the lifting of a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ to powersets $f(S) = \{f(a) \in B| a \in S\}$? This is usually done without comment.

Comment: This would be my first idea too. But if $f \in K \langle A \rangle$ then f is a function. Obviously $\mu$ can’t work with functions, only words or a set of words. Thx for both of your comments.

Comment: Perhaps it's extended from $A^*$ to $K\langle A\rangle$ by $K$-linearity?

Comment: Yes, this is similar to the notation as in Berstel & Reutenauer's book that I linked on the other question. I agree with Emil's guess.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to this topic. Emil or Joshua, would it be possible, if you can give me a simple example.

Comment: $\mu(a)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \mu(b) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\mu(a+b) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \mu(ab+2b) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. People on this question and the other have recommended excellent books that are available online, you should really check them out.

Comment: Oh, thx you very much. Now it makes all sense to me. 

I will check the books out :).